# SQL Server trigger UPDATE on db TABLES FROM ( SELECT FROM a Linked Server (ODBC)

Tags: sql-server, triggers, quickbooks

My goal is to read data from a Quickbooks database with SQL Server and when data in Quickbooks changes, I want to detect update in another database in my LocalServer.

The database on my server that I want to update is named `ambev.dbo`

`SalesOrder` is a table IN `ambev.dbo` (this is relevant for my question).

I have already done the read part from Quickbooks. Created a linked server to get all the data from Quickbooks. Linked server name = QBODBC

I can query from QBODBC perfect so it's set up correctly. One of the tables in this server is 'SalesOrderTable' (relevant for question below).

Now my question is the following: is it possible to create a trigger or something, that if the data in table 'SalesOrderTable' (in linked QBODBC server) is changed, then an update happens against `ambev.dbo.SalesOrder`?

I'm not asking for the code to do this, I'm asking if this is possible to do, if it is then I will try to figure a way to do it. but i need to know first if it's possible

Comment: What is QBODBC?   Is it a SQL Server?   Do you have permission to change it?   Can it be linked to `ambev`?

Comment: QBODBC as State on my post. it is a Linked Server., this is a Read Only,  only want to read if any changes, They linked that it's why its a "Linked Server"

Comment: If you can read `QB` in a SQL query, then you should create a `MERGE` statement to either update or insert rows from `QB`. Run this as a job as frequently as you need.